# passing std::function* to template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, lambda, reference

Since template parameters can only have pointers to objects, and do not allow lambda literals, I've been trying to find a way to capture a lambda and pass it in as a std::function. Since the parameter can't be a plain function, I know it has to be either a reference or a pointer. I've tried both function& = * function_ptr, and function* = &function_ptr, but both come up with errors regarding conversions. Trying & and & leads to `object has no linkage` error. Is it possible to pass in an std::function pointer?

Here is the code I have currently.

```
template<typename type>
std::function<bool(type)>* d = new std::function<bool(type)>([](type element) constexpr -> bool {return element;});

template<typename type = bool, std::function<bool(type)>& lambda = *d<type>>
struct Boolean {

    const type element;

    constexpr inline explicit Boolean(type element_in): element(element_in) {}

    constexpr inline operator bool() {
        return *lambda(element);
    }
};
```

The goal is to effectively pass in an algorithm at compile-time through template parameters. I've thought about using if constexpr and a nullptr default to give the lambda the default I actually mean for it to have, but I don't see why that is necessary.

To be explicit, I've tried:

`*lambda = d<type>`,`*lambda = &d<type>`, `&lambda = &d<type>`, and `&lambda = *d<type>`. Probably others to in my scramble, but I recall these explicitly.

For errors, I recieved:

`* Concepts::Operators::d<bool>’ is not a valid template argument for type ‘std::function<bool(bool)>&’ because it is not an object with linkage`,

and many about incorrect conversions between pointers and references.

I'm hoping someone can elucidate why trying to match a pointer to a reference doesn't seem to be working, as I'm not sure myself.

Much earlier, I also tried just making d as the object itself (`std::function<bool(type)> d = [](type element) constexpr -> bool {return element};`), but I didn't have any luck with this either.
`

Comment: Using your terminology: What was the error message when you tried making `d` as the object itself and `&lambda = d<type>`?

Comment: That...worked. Well, getting rid of the *  off of d's type made this work. I guess if d holds the location of the heaped anonymous lambda, and I then reference that with &lambda, then it works?

Comment: Probably a case of over-thinking things. Without the *, `d` is an instance of a certain class. With the &, `lambda` is a reference to the same class. To initialize a class reference, you give it the class instance to which to refer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `constexpr inline operator bool()` to actually be `constexpr`, you can't use a `std::function`, because it has no constexpr constructor.

However, since you are using constexpr lambdas (C++17), you should also be able to use `auto` type in [template parameters](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters). It can be used to pass a lambda to your template:

```
template<typename type>
auto d = [](type element) constexpr -> bool {
    return element;
};

template<typename type = bool, auto& lambda = d<type>>
struct Boolean {
    const type element;

    constexpr inline explicit Boolean(type element_in): element(element_in) {}

    constexpr inline operator bool() {
        return lambda(element);
    }
};
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/GhRW4lbS5R4MeLyM)